# It is possible to create an intent that recognizes any request made to Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating an Alexa skill, and in this skill, I would like to have a single Intent whose task is to retrieve the requests made that Alexa cannot natively respond to and send them to an external server. Is it possible?

For example, I have created an Intent that handles if there is a parking spot nearby. So if the user asks Alexa "Are there any parking spots nearby?" Alexa, through the created intent, will respond with an appropriate answer.

However, if the user says anything else that is not handled by the set Intents or even by Alexa itself (such as "Roll a dice" or "Tell me a joke"), I would like this request to be retrieved and sent through a POST request to an external server.

Yes, it is possible to create an intent in your Alexa skill that retrieves such requests and sends them to an external server using a POST request. You can set up a webhook or an API endpoint on your server to receive the requests sent by the intent and process them accordingly.

The use case of this skill is handling requests for a hotel through the use of Alexa for Hospital.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently supported by Alexa skill. If this is related to Alexa for Hospitality, I'd recommend contacting Alexa Smart Properties. https://build.amazonalexadev.com/Alexa-Smart-Properties-Contact-Us.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).